# What does it mean to say that an automaton construction is "effective"?

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability, formal-languages, regular-language

Let $L, K \subseteq X^{\ast}$ be languages, then we set
$$
 K^{-1}L := \{ u \in X^{\ast} \mid vu \in L \mbox{ for some } v \in K \}
          = \bigcup_{v\in K} v^{-1}L
$$
with $u^{-1}L := \{ w \in X^{\ast} \mid uw \in L \}$ for $u \in X^{\ast}$. Then in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.6491) (on page 25 and 26) it is shown for regular $L$ and *arbitrary* $K$, the set $K^{-1}L$ is regular. Their proof goes like this, if $\mathcal A = (Q, T, I, F)$ is an automaton for $L$, let $I'$ be the set of states of $\mathcal A$ which are accessible from an initial state of $\mathcal A$ following a path labeled by a word of $K$,
$$
 I' := \{ q \in Q \mid \exists i \in I, \exists u \in K : \mbox{the automaton has a transition from $i$ to $q$ by $u$} \}. 
$$
Then $\mathcal A' = (Q, T, I', F)$ recognizes $K^{-1}L$. $\square$

After that they remark:

> The proof is not effective: we may not be able to construct the set of states $I'$ associated with $K$. However, if $K$ is rational too, then $I'$ is effectively constructible.

What do they mean by "effective", do they mean constructible in finite time? If so, I think it is enough to suppose that $K$ is decidable (i.e. for each $w \in X^{\ast}$ we know in a finite amount of time if $w \in K$ or $w \notin K$). As for reachability in a finite automaton, it is enough to inspect the words of length $\le |Q|$ where $Q$ denotes the states of the automaton, and if $K$ is decidable we can test whether each such word is in $K$ or not, hence this procedure finishes in a finite amount of time. Is this what they want to say? And if so, why they restrict $K$ to be rational, if decidable would be enough? Or do they have some specific automata construction involving $K$ in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "effective" means something like the construction can be carried out in finite time.

But this does not mean that it is enough that $K$ is *decidable*. Consider for example that we could let
$$ K=\{\mathtt{a}^n\mid n\text{ is a perfect number}\} $$
and $L=(\mathtt{aa})^* $.

It is easy enough to specify a way to *decide* $K$, but that does not make it any easier to figure out whether the state of $L$ that corresponds to odd $n$s is reached by a word in $K$ or not.

This example also shows that it can well be necessary to check words in $K$ that are much longer than the number of states in an automaton for $L$.

Comment: I see, the words that are necessary to reach a particular state (in your example the state that corresponds to an odd number of $a$'s) might be arbitrary large, but if $K$ is regular why we do not have this problem?

Comment: @Stefan: If $K$ is regular, then you can do something smarter than enumerate words from it: Take a finite automaton for $K$, and then construct a "product automaton" in which the states are pairs of a $K$-state and an $L$-state. Then it is easy to figure out which pairs are reachable from the initial state, and when a pair whose $K$-state accepts is reachable, the $L$-state is a possible starting point for $K^{-1}L$.

Comment: And in the product automaton it is enough to check words of length $|Q_L|\cdot |Q_K|$ where $Q_L$ and $Q_K$ denote the states of the automata for $L$ respectively $K$?

Comment: @Stefan: You don't need to "check words" at all --the product automaton allows you to compute directly which combinations of $K$-states and $L$-states are reachable if you run the $K$-automaton and the $L$-automaton side-by-side on some input _of any length_.

Comment: But we want to compute the set $I'$ of states reachable by words $u$ from $K$ (from the initial states of $\mathcal A$), so to show that we can do this we need some argument that a finite number of words is enough, or?

Comment: @Stefan: Still no -- no matter how long a word we're imagining, it will always end up in _one_ of the $|Q_L|\cdot|Q_K|$ pairs of states -- and since those finitely many states form a finite graph, we can find out which of them are reachable without worrying about word length. (This argument does also _imply_ that every state pairs that are reached at all is reached by some word of length at most $|Q_L|\cdot|Q_K|$, but that fact is not particularly important here -- in particular, we _do not_ need to enumerate all words up to that length).